# bootstrap navbar toggle not showing in mobile

Tags: html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have a problem with my navbar. When I resize my screen to mobile size and click on the toggle button to uncollapse the menu, nothing happens.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <?php 
            $SQL = "SELECT * from Categories WHERE cat_top='1';";
            $result = $db->execute($SQL);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            ?>
            <li class="pull-right"> <a href="קטגוריה-<?php echo $cat_id;?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="">אודות</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

you've missed the `#` in your `button` `data-target` attribute, the `#` is needed to target the `id` attribute

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <?php 
            $SQL = "SELECT * from Categories WHERE cat_top='1';";
            $result = $db->execute($SQL);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
            $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
            ?>
            <li class="pull-right"> <a href="קטגוריה-<?php echo $cat_id;?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="">אודות</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/gvpg6k47/